# Evaluating a partial derivative with respect to the natural log of a variable

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

How do I evaluate a partial derivative that is expressed as
$$
\frac{\partial \ln \gamma}{\partial \ln x},
$$
where $\gamma$ is a function of $x$?

Is this expression simply short-hand for
$$
\frac{x}{\gamma}\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x},
$$
Or is there more to it?

Comment: If $\gamma$ depends on $x$ alone as the independent variable then I see no need of the partials. That's just $$\frac{\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm d(\gamma)}{\frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx},$$ or simply $$\frac{x\gamma'}{\gamma}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is that $\frac{x}{\gamma}\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial x}$ doesn't require $x,\,\gamma>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true. Consider the function $\gamma=x^{\alpha}, x>0$

We have $\frac{x}{\gamma}\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{x^{\alpha}}\cdot \alpha\cdot x^{\alpha-1}=\alpha$

And $\ln(\gamma)=\alpha\cdot \ln\left(x\right)$ And therefore $\frac{\partial\ln(\gamma)}{\partial\ln\left(x\right)}=\alpha$

That are two ways to express the *elasticity* of a function.